# Drawable Resource Not Found

Tags: android, drawable

All I am attempting to implement a selector drawable resource for a custom `ArrayAdapter`. I am consistently getting a `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/list_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020`

Could anyone offer suggestions?

I have two xml files:

res/drawable/list_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@android:color/black" />
</selector>
```

res/layout/list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/casualty_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, my code loads the list item as follows:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TCCC cur_object = getItem(position);

        View cur_view = convertView;
        if(cur_view == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Inflating!");
            cur_view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_item, null);
            String text_value = (cur_object.m_name.length() == 0) ? "New Casualty" : cur_object.m_name;

            TextView name_box = (TextView)cur_view.findViewById(R.id.casualty_text_view);
            if(name_box != null)
                name_box.setText(text_value);
        }

        return cur_view;
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See if what @Nebraska has suggested helps.

Else, try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Thank you, the drawable did it. Please remove the logic suggestion, it is not applicable to the question.

Comment: Any idea how selectors work btw? I am playing around with changing the background color of a ListView item at run time. One approach was to use `setBackgroundColor()` programmtically, this was easy and worked. The selector (unexpectedly) also works but not correctly. It's not setting the correct colors. Any thoughts on where I can read on view inflation, in other words are selectors only use statically once at inflation or continuously? Or do default `getView()` calls take advantage of them?

Comment: @Constantin Could you define what you are looking for? In what states(or rather what combination of states) do you want the list item to change color?

Comment: Using `setItemChecked` and `getCheckedItemPosition` with a `setChoiceMode(single)`, I can programmatically set the background color of ListView items in my subclassed `ArrayAdapter::getView` function. I was interested in achieving the same results using xml files and selectors, in hopes of improving efficiency.

Comment: You can use states defined here [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html). **Edit**: As for `setItemChecked()`, are you calling that on the TextView?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34410/discussion-between-vikram-and-constantin)

Comment: A couple of links on inflating views: [Inflation is a Good Thing](http://www.androidguys.com/2008/07/09/inflation-is-a-good-thing/) _and_ [Android XML View inflation Tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=303)

Comment: Changing android:color to android:drawable in the selector did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Luis comment is most valuable and accurate sentence in this whole topic... `DRAWABLE`, not `COLOR`, even when pointing on color... (but as far as I remember this was causing some issues < API14, currently not supporting such old devices)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, put them in the hdpi folder, and then clean the project. It will update everything and the error should be gone.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. Cleaned the project, uninstalled the app, same error.

Comment: Those android:color things might have problems with them

Comment: Constantin did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution is I moved the XML drawables to the drawable/ folder and it worked perfectly fine for me. You might want to give it a try.

[VectorDrawableCompat Resources$NotFoundException on KitKat and below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777293/vectordrawablecompat-resourcesnotfoundexception-on-kitkat-and-below)

Answer (score 0):

For me the confusion was that I had replaced all instances of a vector drawable with png, except for one, and this is what was failing. make sure and check all instances of the resource that is giving you the issue, and that all is as expected...

Answer (score 0):

I encounter a similar issue, I was able to fix it by removing a blank line at top of a .xml drawable.