# VectorDrawableCompat Resources$NotFoundException on KitKat and below

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-vectordrawable

When I enable

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

I get a lot of resourceNotFoundExceptions on KitKat and below devices. I get this for NavigationView for Menus and also for ImageViews with app:srcCompat

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02006b
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2305)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:268)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:178)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.initialize(ActionMenuItemView.java:114)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.bindItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:206)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:182)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:192)
at  android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:480)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1138)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:91)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:229)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:284)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1030)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1053)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1345)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1583)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.access$100(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:89)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:128)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:110)
```

for NavigationView

```
Process: org.ligi.gobandroid_hd, PID: 11473
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.ligi.gobandroid_hd/org.ligi.gobandroid_hd.ui.game_setup.GoSetupActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
    at org.ligi.gobandroid_hd.ui.application.GobandroidFragmentActivity.setContentView(GobandroidFragmentActivity.java:85)
    at org.ligi.gobandroid_hd.ui.GoActivity.onCreate(GoActivity.java:108)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
    at org.ligi.gobandroid_hd.ui.application.GobandroidFragmentActivity.setContentView(GobandroidFragmentActivity.java:85) 
    at org.ligi.gobandroid_hd.ui.GoActivity.onCreate(GoActivity.java:108) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020067
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2305)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:268)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:178)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:475)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:436)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:112)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:241)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:169)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:95)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
    at org.ligi.gobandroid_hd.ui.application.GobandroidFragmentActivity.setContentView(GobandroidFragmentActivity.java:85) 
    at org.ligi.gobandroid_hd.ui.GoActivity.onCreate(GoActivity.java:108) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is your gradle version?

Comment: Are you using support library v23.2.0? and your build.gradle has the modifications suggested by the docs (and can be found in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35624744/4860513)?

Comment: 2.11 and build-plugin 2.0.0-beta6

Comment: yes 23.2.0 and the entry in gradle

Comment: Are you using vector drawable? If yes, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020222/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-for-ic-sync-black-24dp-xml

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found the problem: I had my vector-drawables in drawable-anydpi/ - this produces this crash - when i move the drawables to drawable/ it works fine

Comment: Thank you! This is the real answer.

Comment: Thank you, moving from `drawable` to `drawable-nodpi` worked for me.

Comment: This helped me too!

Answer (score 36):

To support versions before Lollipop, use

> com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0 (or later)

support library.

And then, instead of

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(), id);
```

use this one

```
AppCompatResources.getDrawable(view.getContext(), id);
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this worked for us. How did you find out about this?

Comment: Note: AppCompatDrawableManager is a private API so this could be broken at any point. See: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216903#c13

Comment: I got same issue, Then I found that support library was updated and it is not mentioned any where.... Through android developer bugs list I figured out...

Answer (score 5):

I was able to use the vector drawables on **pre-Lollipop** devices by wrapping them in a StateListDrawable (a selector).

More precisely, I created a selector drawable in XML, and then added a **single vector drawable** in them :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/vector_ic_action_add" />
</selector>
```

I then use this "wrapped" drawable in my menu. If you want more information about how it works, check out [this](https://chris.banes.me/2016/02/25/appcompat-vector/) very useful post by Chris Banes.

Comment: I get the exceptions even when I wrap the drawables like this

Comment: i love u man :) it's work !!!!!! i have this problem about 7 days and always search for problems ♥♥♥

Comment: This solution doesn't work for support-library v 25.3.1
Use this one instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/38507596/4579783

Answer (score 5):

To fix this issue, I had to add the following code at the application startup (Application subclass) :

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

In addition to :

- Use `app:srcCompat` in layout definition (ImageButton view in my case) instead of `android:src`.
- Activate in gradle : `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`

Comment: This answer fixed my issue. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

as far as I've read on the docs there's only XML access for ImageView.

For the Menu you'll have to use in java.

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(menuResId);
toolbar.getMenu()
       .findItem(menuItemId)
       .setIcon(VectorDrawableCompat
                       .createFromResource(resource, drawableId);
```

Comment: I also saw nothing on the docs - but as this is basically drawn by appcompat I was wondering if there is some automatism under the hood I am not aware of - menu-items are a big use-case for VectorDrawables - adding this workaround makes the code ugly

Comment: hm - @chrisbanes states in the comments of his blog-post "Menu items work fine. How are you trying to use it with preferences?"

Comment: I did not have to add this and my menu items just worked out of the box with no XML change. I'm using 23.0.4 of the support library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vectorDrawableComapt and setting it in XML remember to do it the correct way:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
```

Source:
https://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Comment: This is related only to `ImageView` not XML in general as you refer.

Answer (score 0):

**I faced same issue but after some hour of wasting solved the issue**

1. Remove drawables make sure just have drawable
2. In build.gradle use

   `defaultConfig {vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true}`

   3. Make set vector drawable to ImageView as below
       `<ImageView
       android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
       android:layout_width="100dp"
       android:layout_height="100dp"
       android:background="@drawable/your_selector"
       app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_your_vector_logo" />`
   4. Your activity must extends AppCompatActiviity instead of Activity

I hope your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was using style reference for solid color `?colorAccent` for a shape. It crash on KitKat but not above. Updated to use actual color code and it goes away.
`<solid android:color="#7885cb" />`

Answer (score 0):

One issue could be the vector itself. One of my paths was like 4k characters long and although there was a warning I just ignored it. Although it was previewing fine, it would crash at run time.