# Resource not found Exception for vector drawables

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am going to run my app on some devices its crashes as logs below:

```
01-04 16:54:02.206 7466-7466/com.lawnmowers E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.lawnmowers, PID: 7466
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lawnmowers/com.lawnmowers.MapActivityNew}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02004f
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02004f
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2099)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:346)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:194)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:182)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:717)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:187)
at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
at com.lawnmowers.MapActivityNew.onCreate(MapActivityNew.java:89)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2095)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700) 
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:346) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:194) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:182) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:717) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:187) 
at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521)    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71) 
at com.lawnmowers.MapActivityNew.onCreate(MapActivityNew.java:89) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As resource not found in `AppCompat` library something. But I already added all required things in **Build.gradle**. Please have a ref:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lawnmowers"
        minSdkVersion 15
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental = true;
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
    }

}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please suggests any solution for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: abc_vector_test.xm file is missing on drawable resources. create that file with their properties.

Comment: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID

Answer (score 6):

You need to add abc_vector_test.xml in the drawable folder.

**Updated:**

You need to use it in AppCompat (activity etc) and moreover more imageView use this tag

```
app:srcCompat=
```

instead of

```
android:src=
```

hope it solves the problem.

Comment: Have you read whole log? Its not my xml file which is missing it is showing in Appcompat library, which is already attached and running on many devices. Please read carefully.

Comment: this is not at all helpful...please try to elaborate the solution.

Comment: Saved my day bro :D

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem in Visual Studio / Xamarin and switching off:

- Use shared runtime
- use fast deployment
- use incremental Android packaging system

in the app project options 
helped in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the same issue, but the symptom was the same.  I was receiving the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.standardbredmobileapp/com.standardbredmobileapp.SplashScreen}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_splash_shapes.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02004f
```

When the application was starting, following the stack trace though, it was actually being caused due to a  in the XML file itself.  Down a few `caused by`s showed that there was an error in parsing the XML file on the older Android versions.

The resolution in my case I had to do the following this: [VectorDrawable: Invalid drawable tag gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854772/vectordrawable-invalid-drawable-tag-gradient)

```
/drawable/ic_splash_shapes.xml 
Contains a <shape> solid with background

/drawable-v24/ic_splash_shapes.xml
Contains the original <gradient> with <item android:offset=""/>
```

This allowed the Splash layout/style/windowBackground to show as "expected" on devices ranging in more versions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the XML drawables to the drawable/ folder? That worked for me.

[VectorDrawableCompat Resources$NotFoundException on KitKat and below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777293/vectordrawablecompat-resourcesnotfoundexception-on-kitkat-and-below)

[Solved: Android Resources$NotFoundException Crash Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466145/solved-android-resourcesnotfoundexception-crash-report)

Answer (score 0):

If this error occurred on android API level 21, 22 or so, using pngs in place of the vector could solve your problem.
It solved for me.