# Android Resources$NotFoundException Crash Report

Tags: java, android, xml

I have been receiving the same crash report throwing an **android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException** error complaining of a missing resource ID.

Could anyone please shed some light what the error is? I've seen some posts talking about NavigationView being the problem. Some others mention about the v21 drawable resources but I don't have any v21 drawables in my app.

If you've seen posts that answer this question, do direct me to them. Otherwise, your kind response will be greatly appreciated!

Below are the stack traces for one of the crash reports.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.raimikarim.arabicconjugator/com.raimikarim.arabicconjugatorpro.Conjugation.SmartConjugateActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2065)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2090)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4802)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:813)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:580)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.raimikarim.arabicconjugatorpro.Conjugation.SmartConjugateActivity.onCreate(SmartConjugateActivity.java:64)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5013)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2029)
... 11 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
... 22 more
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02006c
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1017)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:321)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:192)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:495)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:436)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:112)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:245)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:169)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:95)
```

And here is my styles.xml

```
    <resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_color</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ConjogetAppBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/SpinnerStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- Spinner design -->
<style name="SpinnerStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">#d1d1d1</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">0.5dp</item>
</style>

<!-- App bar style -->
<style name="ConjogetAppBarStyle" parent="style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <!-- Remove the shadow below the app bar -->
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
</style>

<!-- Style for a tab that displays a category name -->
<style name="category_tab" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/primary_dark_color</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/CategoryTabTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<!-- Text appearance style for a category tab -->
<style name="CategoryTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textColor">#A8A19E</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>

<style name="edittext">
    <item name="android:layout_width">140dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">32sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_style</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item> // so that user goes to next edittext after input
</style>
<style name="Theme.Transparent2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

And my styles.xml (**v21**)

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: @Charlie Just made some edits to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I just moved the XML drawables to the drawable/ folder. Works like magic. Thanks to @ligi.

[VectorDrawableCompat Resources$NotFoundException on KitKat and below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777293/vectordrawablecompat-resourcesnotfoundexception-on-kitkat-and-below)

Answer (score 0):

Change styles.xml theme ...

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">#673AB7</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#512DA8</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#00BCD4</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#212121</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#727272</item>

</style>
```

works for me when i remove the android:textColorPrimary and android:textColorSecondary theme items.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">#673AB7</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#512DA8</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#00BCD4</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Does it only work for "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"? I'm using "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar". Sorry, amateur here.

Comment: I imported your style and made one layout with NavigationView, it worked perfect.. Can you post your layout and activity code for more detail?