# Drawable abc_vector_test resource not found exception for Kitkat and below

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-resources, android-4.4-kitkat, android-vectordrawable

This is my stacktrace when I am running my app on Kitkat or below versions

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                       Process: com.threesixteen.app, PID: 1504
>                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.threesixteen.app/com.threesixteen.app.ui.activities.SplashActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080058
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080058
>                                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
>                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:332)
>                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
>                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
>                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:711)
>                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
>                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
>                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:131)
>                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:155)
>                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31)
>                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55)
>                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
>                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
>                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
>                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
>                                                                           at com.threesixteen.app.ui.activities.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:97)
>                                                                           at com.threesixteen.app.ui.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:55)
>                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

This is my gradle file.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
   maven { url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smilefam/SendBird-SDK-Android/master/" }
}

android {
 compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    resConfigs "en"
    applicationId "com.threesixteen.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 115
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionName "1.6.6.5-Debug"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
 buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config         
    }
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
////////////////
////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true// Contains Picasso
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+') {
    exclude module: 'answers-shim'
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.24.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.20.0'
compile 'com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-android-sdk:3.0.28'
compile 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:3.1.2'
compile 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.6.0@aar'
compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.1.4'
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.airbnb.android:epoxy:2.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am also putting this line of code at the start of activity

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

I have also referred to this question where the problem was similar to mine. 
[Resource not found Exception for vector drawables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462731/resource-not-found-exception-for-vector-drawables)

Is the problem related to any libraries that I am using? The resource id **#0x7f080058**  refers to *abc_vector_test* drawable in **R** file. And when I click to see the source of this drawable, it lies in the *AppCompat library and has a private access*.

Please suggest me some way to get rid of this error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63623801) with Android Studio Canary 6, the alpha6 Gradle Plugin, and AAPT2. Switch back to aapt, to alpha5, or use [Android Studio 3.0 Canary 7](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/07/android-studio-30-canary-7-is-now.html), which fixes this issue.

Comment: Its still there. even with beta 2

Answer (score 0):

If your "abc_vector_test drawable" is empty, you can see this error on some devices. The empty is:

```
<vector xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width = "24dp"
        android:height = "24dp"
        android:viewportHeight = "24.0"
        android:viewportWidth = "24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor = "#00000000"
        android:pathData = ""/>
</vector>
```