# Android invalid color state list tag gradient

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable, lg

I've an app with over 5000 downloads and more than 500 users active daily and out of nowhere I started get an weird error on Crashlytics:

```
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-anydpi-v24/ic_tickets.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700b3
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2748)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2643)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:921)
       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:703)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:76)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:72)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)


Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-anydpi-v24/$ic_tickets__0.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f070017
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateListForCookie(Resources.java:2858)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2807)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:439)
       at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawable.java:1605)
       at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:1584)
       at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflateInternal(VectorDrawable.java:666)
       at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:571)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1215)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1124)


Caused by org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #6: invalid color state list tag gradient
       at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateList.java:217)
       at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXml(ColorStateList.java:201)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateListForCookie(Resources.java:2854)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2807)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:439)
       at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawable.java:1605)
```

The stack trace is way longer than this, more than 500 lines on Crashlytics, I pasted here what I thought might be useful to understand the problem.

If I got it right it is complaining like one of my resources is missing or corrupted; what could it be?

But the resource is intact in the apk:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="512"
    android:viewportWidth="512" android:width="24dp"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:pathData="M381.845,292.27c0,11.032 -8.943,19.975 -19.975,19.975s-19.975,-8.943 -19.975,-19.975c0,-11.032 8.943,-19.975 19.975,-19.975S381.845,281.238 381.845,292.27zM361.869,332.221c-11.032,0 -19.975,8.943 -19.975,19.975s8.943,19.975 19.975,19.975s19.975,-8.943 19.975,-19.975S372.902,332.221 361.869,332.221zM361.869,392.147c-11.032,0 -19.975,8.943 -19.975,19.975s8.943,19.975 19.975,19.975s19.975,-8.943 19.975,-19.975S372.902,392.147 361.869,392.147zM307.418,136.36c-9.983,4.696 -14.268,16.596 -9.572,26.578c4.696,9.983 16.596,14.268 26.578,9.572c9.983,-4.696 14.268,-16.596 9.572,-26.578C329.3,135.95 317.401,131.664 307.418,136.36zM451.759,352.197c0,22.029 17.922,39.951 39.951,39.951h19.975V512H0.314V392.147H20.29c22.029,0 39.951,-17.922 39.951,-39.951s-17.922,-39.951 -39.951,-39.951H0.314V192.393h0.509l-0.042,-0.089L408.489,0l50.866,108.128l-17.013,8.861c-13.29,6.921 -21.544,20.506 -21.544,35.453c0,22.029 17.922,39.951 39.951,39.951h50.937v119.853H491.71C469.681,312.246 451.759,330.168 451.759,352.197zM94.244,192.393h297.352c-6.822,-11.763 -10.75,-25.403 -10.75,-39.951c0,-23.307 10.023,-44.953 27.021,-59.913l-18.505,-39.335l-81.134,38.269c4.355,9.886 0.068,21.491 -9.762,26.115c-9.818,4.618 -21.473,0.536 -26.323,-9.095L94.244,192.393zM411.808,352.197c0,-37.163 25.503,-68.482 59.926,-77.374v-42.479h-89.889c0,11.032 -8.943,19.975 -19.975,19.975s-19.975,-8.943 -19.975,-19.975H40.265v42.479c34.424,8.891 59.926,40.211 59.926,77.374s-25.503,68.482 -59.926,77.374v42.479h301.629c0,-11.032 8.943,-19.975 19.975,-19.975s19.975,8.943 19.975,19.975h89.889V429.57C437.31,420.678 411.808,389.36 411.808,352.197z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="256.00745" android:endY="511.99982"
                android:startX="256.00745"
                android:startY="-0.0150070675" android:type="linear">
                <item android:color="#FF2AF598" android:offset="0"/>
                <item android:color="#FF009EFD" android:offset="1"/>
            </gradient>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
</vector>
```

The drawable is a very small and simple icon for a button in the app, I downloaded it from a icon library it opens and run fine on all my tests.

The second weird thing about this is that over 500 active users I had today this is happening only with 4 users all with the same smartphone:

```
Device
Brand: LGE
Model: LG K10 LTE
Orientation: Portrait
RAM free: 170.92 MB
Disk free: 574.64 MB
Operating System
Version: 6.0
Orientation: Portrait
Rooted: No
Crash
```

Is there any know issue about this smartphone model? What can I do in order to fix this for the affected users?

Comment: two years later and still getting this only on LG G4 with Marshmallow... :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is because you use a few attributes not supported prior to API level `24`.

eg. `startX`, `endX`, `startY`, `endY` and `offset`.

Android Marshmallow `6.0` is API level `23` ...

That `invalid color state list tag gradient` is coming from the `offset`:

```
<item android:color="#FF2AF598" android:offset="0"/>
<item android:color="#FF009EFD" android:offset="1"/>
```

This issue most likely isn't `LG` specific, but `Marshmallow` specific.

Comment: it's funny because it WORKS in api 16 on my emulator and in MANY OTHERS REAL SMARTPHONES... i'm having this problem only with that specific cellphone. My app minSdkLevel is 16 and many many users are using it below 23 without problems

Comment: @RafaelLima as a matter of fact, the `Drawable` should not look the same, with half of the attributes not being considered ...you could add a `drawable-v23` without the gradient - or use `PNG` or `WEBP` instead. see the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable

Comment: i used android studio conversor to transform the svg file into xml drawable, is there any conversor you know that would make it portable prior 23?

Comment: @RafaelLima you can use the support library, to render SVG to PNG, for backwards compatibility (no need to manually add the resources, it happens at build time, when configured).

Comment: Thank you, I wish there was a documentation that clearly states that. I googled around for a while and couldn't find any, and Android Studio doesn't even warn on these.

Comment: Related answer to solve : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47918358/14784590 keep a png in drawable, and vector in drawable-v24

Answer (score 9):

Use `app:srcCompat` instead of `src` on the `ImageView`

In your app `build.gradle` write below code :

```
android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

defaultConfig {
    ...
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    ...
}
```

Now you see it works.

Answer (score 4):

The actual problem is with attributes you are defining like `android:fillColor`
which expects to be a single value color and not a list of colors like gradient or color list. It works from API 24. My suggestion is to tell your designer to create exact logo for below 24 API

[Refer to the link for more details](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .xml to set the image resource, just set the image resource programmatically from your java code.

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue in Android API 21-23 with the vector drawable. By using this, now its fixed

> app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_placeholder"

and by programmatically:

> Drawable img = button.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(
> R.drawable.ic_brush );
> button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( img, null, null, null);