# InflateException with app:srcCompat in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-appcompat

When using app:srcCompat with a vector drawable in my .xml layout I'm unable to run code on a device running android 4.2.1. For instance I have a FAB like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    ...
    android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"/>
```

where **ic_add** is a vector drawable:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M19,13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
```

This works fine on Lollipop, but crashes on a device running android 4.2.1:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                                at info.samuilife.samuiplus.user.offers.OffersFragment.onCreateView(OffersFragment.kt:34)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2239)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1332)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1574)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2034)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:651)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1239)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1087)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1613)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15604)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4918)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:713)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1389)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:783)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15604)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4918)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15604)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4918)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15604)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4918)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15604)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4918)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15604)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4918)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2191)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15604)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2165)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1443)
```

Without the app:srcCompat line it works fine.

In my build.gradle I also have:

```
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    ...
}

...

dependencies {
      ...
        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1"
}
```

What am I missing here? Any thoughts/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

**Solution:** 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35836318/4656400) answer worked for me.

Comment: Vector images are not supported in Android Api level 19 or below

Answer (score 1):

You probably forget to add the design support library. So, you should add the Design support library in your dependency by adding the following line:

```
dependencies {
      ...
  compile "com.android.support:design:27.0.0"
  //compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1"
}
```

You don't need to add the appcompat library because it's implicitly included in design support library. And please remember to never using an alpha version of library in your code.

Read more about design support library at [Using the Design Support Library](https://developer.android.com/training/material/design-library.html)

---

**UPDATE**

Add the [Vector Drawable Support](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#vector) with:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.0"
```

Comment: Thanks for advice! I've updated support design library to version 27.0.0. But the problem still remains.

Comment: @AlexKost: I've updated the answer. Adding the vector drawable support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> Android Api level 19 or below does not support Vector images ,I got
>   this solution
>
> Set your widget id here and remove the vector Drawable from that
>   widget

```
private void setBackgrounds(){

        Drawable drawableLeft = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(modelet.getContext(), R.drawable.ic_local_taxi_black_16dp);
        modelet.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawableLeft, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: "You can use VectorDrawableCompat back to API level 7" as stated here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html#vector-drawables-backward-solution